# what does Fix Version/s:6 and Resolved In Build: b19?

Tags: java, version-control

I am new to java.
I have quick query as below.
what does Fix Version/s:6 and Resolved In Build: b19?
Does it mean jdk 1.6.19?

Regards,
L.Dhake

Answer (score 0):

The build number is an additional level of detail of the JDK version :

> Oracle periodically makes updates available and, when an update
>   occurs, the version string will also include the update version
>   number. So, JDK 7 update 4, or JDK 7u4, will have the version string
>   "1.7.0_4". When invoking the java -fullversion command, the result
>   also includes the build number, a level of detail not needed by most
>   users.

For example :

> Java™ SE Development Kit 7, Update 60 (JDK 7u60) The full version
>   string for this update release is **1.7.0_60-b19** (where "b" means
>   "build"). The version number is 7u60.

References :

[Java™ Platform Standard Edition 7 Names and Versions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-naming-418744.html)

[Java™ SE Development Kit 7, Update 60 (JDK 7u60)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u60-relnotes-2200106.html)